# how to define the method openstream for String url in android

Tags: android, string, url

in my app i am trying to parse an xml file from a url. My url contains some Strings which values are got from an edit box in another activity. In mu coding i got error in the following line

```
xmlreader.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
```

A red line is shown in the word openStream, it says that
`"The method openStream() is undefined for the type String"`

please tell me how to define a openStream method for a url which is a String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*how to define the method openstream for String url in android*

you can't String is final class

You need to use some HTTP client library and download the content from the internet.

You may also use `URL` class like `new URL(url).openStream()` but remeber to use it on non UI thread.